# updating URL with AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, highcharts

Is it possible to make an AJAX function that can pass a variable to the URL without refreshing the page?

You see I have a graph being rendered to my page using the Highcharts API. It knows which graph to render by checking what variable is in the URL.

So the idea is I can make buttons on the page that will update the URL seamlessly and therefore update the graph seamlessly. No refreshing required.

Comment: `"to the URL"`, what do you mean ? you want to store key value pairs in the actual url, or send data to the server ? Please elaborate

Comment: Refreshing the page is **never** part of an AJAX process.

Comment: You cannot directly modify the entire URL string for security purposes. You can instead, use hash values, or you can use the history API to use pop/push state. This sounds more like a limitation put in place by the development process. perhaps you should do `if/else` and respond accordingly if no URL variable is present.

Comment: @MMM What are you talking about? I know it's not part of AJAX. Where did I say I WANTED to refresh the page?

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer I just want to store key value pairs in the url e.g. www.blah.com?var=10

Comment: @AzzyDude: Your question is confusing. You want to use AJAX to change the URL (?) without refreshing the page. This either sounds like you think that AJAX would refresh the page, or you incorrectly believe that AJAX can be used to change the URL.

Comment: @MMM Well that is the basis of my question. I specifically open with "is it possible" to change the URL without refreshing the page. I'm assuming if it was possible, it'd be an AJAX function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTML5 History-API. Push a new state into the history. Have a look at the demos at history.js (https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

EDIT: for jquery you can use jQuery Address: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/